# dtype=float32 is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow

Подскажите, в чем ошибка? выбивает на загрузке весов. файла .h5 
метод :

```
def get_distance(im1, im2):
    K.clear_session()
    model = deep_rank_model()
    K.clear_session()
    # for layer in model.layers:
    #     print (layer.name, layer.output_shape)
    K.clear_session()
    model.load_weights("./deepranking.h5")
    K.clear_session()
    image1 = Image.open(urlopen(im1))

    # image1 = load_img(im1)
    image1 = img_to_array(image1).astype("float64")
    image1 = transform.resize(image1, (224, 224))
    image1 *= 1. / 255
    image1 = np.expand_dims(image1, axis=0)

    embedding1 = model.predict([image1, image1, image1])[0]

    image2 = Image.open(urlopen(im2))

    # image2 = load_img(im2)
    image2 = img_to_array(image2).astype("float64")
    image2 = transform.resize(image2, (224, 224))
    image2 *= 1. / 255
    image2 = np.expand_dims(image2, axis=0)

    embedding2 = model.predict([image2, image2, image2])[0]

    distance = sum([(embedding1[idx] - embedding2[idx]) ** 2 for idx in range(len(embedding1))]) ** 0.5

    print(distance)
    return distance
```

**Ниже app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import request

from deepranking_get_distance import get_distance

app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def get_tasks():
        jsondata = request.get_json()
        urls = jsondata["urls"]
        dis = get_distance(urls[0], urls[1])
        return jsonify(dis)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

**Стектрейс:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\PycharmProjects\image-similarity-deep-ranking1\app.py", line 30, in get_tasks
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_comm import CMD_SET_BREAK, CMD_SET_NEXT_STATEMENT, CMD_STEP_INTO, CMD_STEP_OVER, \
  File "C:\Users\gibki\PycharmProjects\image-similarity-deep-ranking1\deepranking_get_distance.py", line 61, in get_distance
    model.load_weights("./deepranking.h5")
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1166, in load_weights
    f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 1058, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2470, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\gibki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1095, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

НО!!!! ПРИ ЗАПУСКЕ СЕРВЕРА И ПРИ ПЕРВОЙ ОТПРАВКЕ ЗАПРОСА - ЗАПРОС ПРОХОДИТ! А УЖЕ ПОСЛЕДУЮЩИЕ ЗАПРОСЫ ВЫДАЕТ КОД ОШИБКИ 500